# Pure Javascript Div Click Check

Tags: javascript

I have div containing svg like this i want to do something when this dive click event how can i do

Code

```js
if (document.getElementById("isparta").onclick) {
  alert('ok')
};
```

```html
<g id="isparta" data-plakakodu="32" data-alankodu="246" data-iladi="Isparta">
  test click
</g>
```

Comment: https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right lines.

There are several ways to attach an Event Listener like `onclick` but a standard unobtrusive approach in modern Javascript would be to:

- grab the DOM element
- declare a named function
- apply the `.addEventListener()` method to the element, with the named function as callback

---

**Example:**

```
const isparta = document.getElementById('isparta');

const activateAlert = () => { alert('ok'); };

isparta.addEventListener('click', activateAlert, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go. It's just a syntax mistake. onclick should receive a function like following:

```js
document.getElementById("isparta").onclick = function() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<g id="isparta" data-plakakodu="32" data-alankodu="246" data-iladi="Isparta">
  test click
</g>
```

Comment: how can i do this with if query make an event if clicked

Comment: It's not done like that. You don't need and if to check if the button is clicked or not. The click event is saved in the DOM and it is fired when you click the button. No need for if, the browser does this automatically.

Comment: @EyüpFidan please accept the answer if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the `onclick` function in HTML.

```
<g id="isparta" data-plakakodu="32" data-alankodu="246" data-iladi="Isparta" onclick="alert('hello')">
  test click
</g>
```

OR if you want more lines of code just give the name of the function, in html and define the function in JavaScript:

```
<g id="isparta" data-plakakodu="32" data-alankodu="246" data-iladi="Isparta" onclick="myFunction()">
  test click
</g>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("hello"); 
}
```